# Using python dictionary as a temporary in-memory key-value database?

Tags: python, caching, key-value-store

I need something like a temporary in-memory key-value store. I know there are solutions like Redis. But I wonder if using a python dictionary could work? And potentially be even faster?
So think a Tornado (or similar) server running and holding a python dictionary in memory and just return the appropriate value based on the HTTP request.

Why I need this?
As part of a service there are key values being stored but they have this property: the more recent they are the more likely they are to be accessed. So I want to keep say last 100 key values in memory (as well as writing to disk) for faster retrieval.

If the server dies the dictionary can be restored again from disk.

Has anyone done something like this? Am I totally missing something here?

PS: I think it's not possible with a WSGI server, right? Because as far as I know you can't keep something in memory between individual requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd definitely work with memcached. Once it has been setup you can easily decorate your functions/methods like it's done in my example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import memcache
import hashlib

def memoize(f):

    def newfn(*args, **kwargs):
        mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
        # generate md5 out of args and function
        m = hashlib.md5()
        margs = [x.__repr__() for x in args]
        mkwargs = [x.__repr__() for x in kwargs.values()]
        map(m.update, margs + mkwargs)
        m.update(f.__name__)
        m.update(f.__class__.__name__)
        key = m.hexdigest()

        value = mc.get(key)
        if value:
            return value
        else:
            value = f(*args, **kwargs)
            mc.set(key, value, 60)
            return value
        return f(*args)

    return newfn

@memoize
def expensive_function(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print expensive_function('abc')
    print expensive_function('abc')
```

Don't care about network latency since that kind of optimization will be a waste of *your* time.

Answer (score 3):

An in process Python dictionary is *way* faster than a memcached server. According to a non-rigorous benchmark that I performed some days ago, a single get takes around 2us using an in process python dictionary and around 50us using a memcached server listening on localhost. In my benchmark, I was using libmemcached as C client and python-libmemcached as python wrapper over this C-client.

Answer (score 1):

If you are bundling the dictionary into the same server as is running your actual service, then yes, that would work fine.

---

If you're creating separate things, well, this is basically what `memcached` is for. [Don't reinvent the wheel.](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/)

Answer (score 1):

I am experimenting with something similar, and the corecache library is a great way to test a few caching systems.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cachecore

In particular, their SimpleCache implementation relies on a vanilla python dict, and in my preliminary tests it's extremely fast, 10x faster than calling memcached locally (assuming I'm already in the python application that needs caching, probably the tornado service in your case).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and it is much faster than redis/memcache because of no network latency. You can use cPickle to dump the dictionary every once in a while. It's tricky though if your program spawns sub processes, then updating the values in one process doesn't affect the other.

Comment: Given that the OP is referring to a Tornado server brokering requests to the dict... there's still going to be network latency.

Comment: @amber but not to memcache/redis.

Comment: What the OP seems to be suggesting is *reimplementing* memcache/redis via tornado.

Comment: it will still be faster than using torando as a proxy to memcache.

Comment: ...Who said anything about using tornado as a proxy to memcache? The point would be not using tornado at all. (This all depends on what the OP meant, though.)

Comment: I agree with @Amber here. It seems clear to me that the OP is suggesting using tornado simply to serve the key/value store via http requests... in which case he would be reinventing the memcached wheel

Comment: unless you need HTTP access to it for some reason, in which case it makes sense. But without asking OP, I'd guess he/she has some more logic in their app than just this. I use dictionaries in my apps when I need data that needs to be even closer than redis/memcache and is volatile, and it can accelerate stuff considerably. Embedding redis as a python module would be a great project BTW, but I don't have time doing it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could just cache last data in dict, nobody prohibits about it and it works in one-server environment
2. When new data added - store it to some redis (memcachedb)
3. When server restarts - just load newest N records to dictionary

All depends on data volume. I believe it takes more memory to keep complex structures in dictionary in python, thought access will be fast - yes